# Good, free, easy-to-use C graphics libraries?

Tags: c, linux, graphics

I was wondering if there were any good free graphics libraries for C that are easy to use?
It's for plotting 2d and 3d graphs and then saving to a file. It's on a Linux system and there's no gnuplot on the system right now.

Or would it just be simpler to switch to another language, and if so which one would be easy to learn?

Comment: What type of graphics?  2D, 3D, both?  How about platform?  Windows, Linux, Mac, portable?

Comment: May you be a little bit more specific what such a library should do? Handle Images? Generate Charts? 3D-modeling?

Comment: Is there something specific you plan to do (such as plotting and graphing, image manipulation, diagrams) or just general purpose graphics? Are you going to display these graphics to the screen or save to a file? Do you need 2D graphics or 3D graphics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To plot 2D and 3D graphs in C I would recommend the library [DISLIN](http://www.mps.mpg.de/dislin/). You can see examples [here](http://www.mps.mpg.de/1757268/exa_c#section_1) or [there](http://www.mps.mpg.de/1757268/exa_c#section_10).

The code is pretty easy to use and gives nice results.

Comment: You forgot to mention that dislin licenses are quite expensive.

From the technical side I would add that the library is not namespaced in any way which makes it hard to use in complex scenarios, e.g. when you mix with your own code and can't see the interfaces.

Comment: The site says "DISLIN is free for non-commercial use." Just my two cents.

Comment: Yes, as long as you don't use it for commercial purposes, DISLIN is completely free.

Comment: It seems to have aged poorly. I was unable to download the manual.

Answer (score 6):

I like the [Cairo library](http://www.cairographics.org/). It has a nice interface to C and it can output in many formats.

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit vague, "graphics" is a wide field. You can get pretty far using just plain [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/), but it might also be considered "too low-level". You need to provide more requirements.

Answer (score 2):

There's [Clutter](http://www.clutter-project.org/). Here are a few snippets from the about page:

"Clutter is an open source software library for creating fast, visually rich, portable and animated graphical user interfaces."

"Clutter aims to be non specific — it implements no particular User Interface style, but rather provides a rich generic foundation that facilitates rapid and easy creation of higher level tool kits tailored to specific needs."

"Developed in C, with language bindings for Perl, Python, C#, C++, Vala and Ruby."

"Scene-graph of layered 2D interface elements manipulated in 3D space via position, grouping, transparency, scaling, clipping and rotation."

I haven't tried it out myself, but it seems pretty flexible if you are looking for something just to play around with.

Answer (score 2):

I've used netpbm format a few time when I needed something simple.

That's how I found out that `qsort()` (in my implementation and for the data provided) performs a merge sort!

[image: qsort]

Source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 20
#define MAX_VALUE 10

unsigned char arr[ARRAY_SIZE];

void print_array(const void *left, const void *right) {
  static int imgs = 0;
  int k, j;
  FILE *img;
  char fname[100];
  char rgb[100];

  if (++imgs > 9999) return;
  sprintf(fname, "img/img%04d.ppm", imgs);
  /* create image in "img/" directory */
  img = fopen(fname, "w");
  if (img) {
    fprintf(img, "P3\n%d %d\n255\n", ARRAY_SIZE, MAX_VALUE);
    for (j=0; j<MAX_VALUE; j++) {
      for (k=0; k<ARRAY_SIZE; k++) {
        int colour = 0;
        if (left && left == arr+k) colour = 2;
        if (right && right == arr+k) colour = 2;
        if (arr[k] == MAX_VALUE - j - 1) colour = 1;
        switch (colour) {
          default: sprintf(rgb, "%d %d %d", 255, 255, 255); break;
          case 1: sprintf(rgb, "%d %d %d", 0, 0, 0); break;
          case 2: sprintf(rgb, "%d %d %d", 255, 0, 0); break;
        }
        }
        fprintf(img, "%s\n", rgb);
      }
    }
    fclose(img);
  } else {
    perror("img fopen");
  }
}

int cmp(const void *left, const void *right) {
  const unsigned char a = *(const unsigned char*)left;
  const unsigned char b = *(const unsigned char*)right;

  print_array(left, right);
  if (a < b) return -1;
  if (a == b) return 0;
  return 1;
}

int main(void) {
  int k;
  unsigned int seed = 0; /* or time(0) */

  srand(seed);
  for (k=0; k<ARRAY_SIZE; k++) {
    arr[k] = rand() % MAX_VALUE;
  }
  print_array(NULL, NULL);
  qsort(arr, (size_t)ARRAY_SIZE, sizeof *arr, cmp);
  print_array(NULL, NULL);
  /* use imagemagick to convert group of files to .gif */
  system("convert -delay 0"
         " img/img*.ppm"
         " -loop 1 img/libc-qsort2.gif");
  /* remove .ppm files */
  system("rm img/" "*ppm"); /* ... my editor does not like a
                                   slash and a star together,
                                   even inside quotes */

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the [Qt](http://qtsoftware.com) GUI toolkit, coupled with the open-source [QwtPlot](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) and [QwtPlot3D](http://qwtplot3d.sourceforge.net/). It's implemented in C++, easy-to-use, extensible, and free...

Answer (score 0):

Most people use the [gd library](https://bitbucket.org/libgd/gd-libgd/) for rendering from C but you must implement the "math plotting" part.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at PGPLOT. It's old but works great and should be in the repos. PLPLOT is also an option, it's similar and newer and should also be readily available in the repos. They're both extremely powerful and can do what you specified.