# How to print window console font in c++ graphics

Tags: c++

[image]

When using outtextxy() in graphic.h, I can only use limited number of font. How can I display the very basic font above? It is just the normal window console raster font.

Comment: Note for those who (like me) didn't already know: `graphic.h` is a [non-standard header used by Borland](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4574201/4200092).

Comment: What do you mean by "display the very basic font"? Did you mean "use the very basic font"?

Comment: i mean printing text with that font

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Console  Raster is not in the list enumerated below - you may want to use `installuserfont` and then use the installed font in `settextstyle`.

You have to make .CHR file that contains the console raster font -

```
enum font_names 
{ 
   DEFAULT_FONT, 
   TRIPLEX_FONT, 
   SMALL_FONT, 
   SANS_SERIF_FONT,
   GOTHIC_FONT, 
   SCRIPT_FONT, 
   SIMPLEX_FONT, 
   TRIPLEX_SCR_FONT,
   COMPLEX_FONT, 
   EUROPEAN_FONT, 
   BOLD_FONT 
};
   userfont = installuserfont("CONSOLE_RASTER.CHR"); /* install font file with console raster */

   settextstyle(userfont, HORIZ_DIR, 4);    /* select the user font */

   outtextxy(x, y, "Hello World!");    /* output some text */
```

Those .CHR file store Stroked fonts - where each stem of the glyph is represented by one line down the center of the stem, and the line is later drawn with a certain width.  You have to make available the  console Raster  in .CHR format.

BTW, it has been almost 20 years since I looked at these BGI functions!

Though I hope you have considered *modern* graphics libraries.

Comment: can you plz suggest some modern libaries, which is not really complex to learn?

Comment: I have used OpenGL for 2D and Qt for GUI - other options are discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701728/graphics-library-in-c

Comment: Also check SDL at http://www.libsdl.org/  - you should also consider Win32 GDI - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx . If it was me  I will start with Win32 GDI .

Comment: I thought Win32 GDI is complicated, as it need to be work in "Win32 GUI Project" but not the usual "console application", and each function have millions of parameters...

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937163/drawing-in-a-win32-console-on-c  those additional parameters are usually for the device context and message - once you understand them it becomes easy. Or try OpenGL - in the long run using either of them will benefit you the most.