# Visual representation of calculated angles

Tags: c, graphics, accelerometer, sensors, gyroscope

OK so I don't even know how to research my problem because I don't know any terms to describe it. So here it is:

I am using an IMU to measure the lying angle and bed inclination for bedbound patients. Is there a way for me to show these results graphically? I mean, is it possible to have a dummy on the screen in a way that I can control his lying angle using C?

I would greatly appreciate it if you let me know if you have any knowledge about possible ways to do it.

Comment: This question could be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701728/graphics-library-in-c. I think you're looking for a graphics library. Perhaps you can link those variables to properties of some shapes, including their position and rotation.

Comment: Quite seriously, have you tried typing a reasonable subset of your question into a search engine? That would be an excellent starting point.

Comment: Yes, you can use a C program to draw graphics on a screen.  There are innumerable ways.